# mod_rewrite code check double rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Here is my current config:

> 1.RewriteRule ^india/news.php /portal/india/stories/telugu.php??topicid=14
>
> 2.RewriteRule ^india/telugu.php?currentpage=([0-9]+).&topicid=14 /portal/india/stories/telugu.php?currentpage=$1&topicid=14

Rule 1 rewrites http://www.domain.com/portal/india/stories/telugu.php?topicid=14 to 
http://www.domain.com/india/news.php which works fine.

Rule 2 should rewrite http://www.domain.com/portal/india/stories/telugu.php?currentpage=p.no&topicid=14 to http://www.domain.com/india/telugu.php?currentpage=p.no&topicid=14 which doesn't work.

It shows a 404 not found.

Here p.no = numeric number

If I need to elaborate my problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule uses regular expressions so having a ? in the regular expressions is not denoting a query string but instead kicking off as a regular expressions key.

Also RewriteRule really only looks at the request URI and ignores the query string unless you set a conditional for the query string.

so Rule 2 should be something like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} currentpage=([0-9]+).&topicid=14
RewriteRule ^india/telugu.php /portal/india/stories/telugu.php?currentpage=%1&topicid=14
```

Please note that in this setup you need %1 instead of $1

I hope this helps I have had this issue several times and this is the only way I ever get it to work. Also you can test rewrites before you do them on sites like http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/